# Android - SharedPreferences's getString prints the default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've tried to save the string `TRUE` and call it right away to check if it is successfully saved, but the result continuously spits `0`, which is the default value. What is wrong with my code?

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("doublePoint", "TRUE");
String doublePoint = settings.getString("doublePoint", "0");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), doublePoint,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do add `editor.commit()` to save it :

```kotlin
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("doublePoint", "TRUE");
editor.commit(); // This command saves the data

String doublePoint = settings.getString("doublePoint", "0");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), doublePoint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

EDIT: As specified in the comment by `Tyler V`, you have two solutions:

- `commit()`: this saves the value and return `true` if the new values were successfully written. The action is performed on the `Main Thread` and you might experiences freeze if the operation takes too long.
- `apply()`: this saves the changes to the in-memory `SharedPreferences` immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

PS: it's safe to replace any instance of `commit()` with `apply()` if you were already ignoring the return value.

Source : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: In general it's recommended to use `editor.apply()` instead of `editor.commit()`. The value will still be available immediately but the write to disk is done in the background [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `commit()` once you put a value in SharedPreferences. Just add that one in this way:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit().commit();
editor.putString("doublePoint", "TRUE"); 
String doublePoint = settings.getString("doublePoint", "0"); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), doublePoint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

For more info, check out this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).